# Python Regular Expression to split SI Units

Tags: python, regex

Im currently breaking my head on this Problem:

I have a list of SI units as follows:

```
units = ['m', 'g', 's', 'A', 'K', 'mol', 'cd', 'Hz', 'N', 'Pa', 'J', 'W', 'C', 'V', 'Ω', 'S', 'F', 'T', 'Wb', 'H', '°C', 'rad', 'sr', 'lm', 'lx', 'Bq', 'Gy', 'Sv', 'kat', '°F', 'thou', 'inch', 'foot', 'yard', 'chain', 'furlong', 'mile', 'league', 'bar', 'min', 'h']
```

Also a list of supported prefixes:

```
prefixes = ['y', 'z', 'a', 'f', 'p', 'n', 'µ', 'm', 'c', 'd', '', 'da', 'h', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y']
```

My goal is refactoring combinations of these units and prefixes to have "*" between units but not between prefix and unit.

For example:

```
def convert(input):
       # re magic
       return result

assert convert("kWh") == "kW*h"
assert concert("W") == "W"
assert concert("min") == "min"
assert concert("As") == "A*s"
```

The function should work for all possible combinations.
What i tried so far is creating a pattern to match every possible combination:

```
unitPattern = "|".join([f"{unit}" for unit in prefixes])
for unit in units:
      for prefix in prefixes:
            unitPattern += f"|{prefix}{unit}"
```

And then refactoring as follows:

```
result = "*".join(re.findall(unitPattern, input))
```

This works for some cases, but for example for "min" as input the result is "m" because the m as single unit matches here before min.

**SOLVED**

The solution i finally came up with is to first generate a pattern to match every unit and prefix combination and then sort this pattern in descending order:

```
unitPattern = sorted(unitPattern, key=len, reverse=True)
```

Finally to insert a "*" where needed i used re.sub:

```
unit = re.sub(f"({unitPattern})({unitPattern})", r"\1*\2", unit)
```

Comment: Have you tried sorting the units by descresing length ? To avoid the m/min problem ?

Comment: Thank you so much, this  was the pice i was missing. I really don't know why i did not come to this solution on my own ^^.